# Performing Geographic Weighted Regression (GWR) in Java?

Tags: java, regression, geographically-weighted-regression

Is there any existing GWR (Geographic Weighted Regression) packages in Java?

The packages should be able to conduct the basic GWR, the bandwidth optimation and some significance test.